# Should we allow for the ability to embedded Nico Nico Douga videos?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

**What is Nico Nico Douga?**

[Nico Nico Douga](http://www.nicovideo.jp/), a video sharing site from Japan, much like YouTube.

**Why embed Nico Nico Douga content?**

If you do directly to the video link, it requires you to log in in order to view the video, but if the video is embedded, you can watch the video without logging in.

**Why Nico Nico Douga?**

A lot of interesting anime/manga/otaku subculture memes (for better or for worse) originated from NND, one of the most notable ones are "Bad Apple!!"

By allowing embedded link access we can possibly allow users to better reference or expand upon the origin of these memes and other subculture references from sources not typically available on via sources like YouTube. E.g., Use better and up-to-date comparisons of MADs from NND for reference to [this question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3916/are-mad-and-amv-synonyms-for-anime-music-video).

Comment: As an addnum, do we want to be able to embed YouTube videos as well? Do we need that one?

Comment: While I'm in favor of this, I think getting Youtube embedding is a higher priority. Also, unless I'm mistaken, Nico doesn't allow embedding without prior permission, which could be more work to get than it's worth.

Comment: I don't really like embedded video in general. In the particular case of NND, @LoganM is correct to point out that there are technical issues surrounding embedding. A better solution (IMO) is to use [Nicoviewer](http://nicoviewer.net/), which basically allows you to view videos on NND as if you were logged in. (Nicoviewer isn't embeddable either, but it removes the barrier to viewing that exists on NND.)

Comment: [MMCafe](http://www.mmcafe.com/nico.html) seems to do the same thing and has an English interface (not for the NND embed itself, but for the embedding page).

Comment: @LoganM When Nico Nico Douga updated their site to version "(9)" they apparently got rid of the annoying restriction of the referral domain to embed their videos with the player.